# Found an error when I open my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I see this when I visit my website:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php on line 90

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-settings.php' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php on line 90
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions warning and error. When your xampp server tries to construct a page using Wordpress it needs access to various Wordpress files so that it can take your settings and configuration into account.

The warning and the error you have given are saying that the "wp-settings.php" file is not readable by the webserver (xampp in this case). Make sure that the xampp user has permission to access "C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php". If you do not know which user you need to give permission to then you can use [the top answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as) to help you find out.

Here is a link to an article on [Wordpress permissions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/). There are many more out there which can also help you to set the required permissions for Wordpress to run properly.

Comment: its not my in localhost its on server site